# vsftpd hide version on port scan

Tags: linux, vsftpd, nmap

I'm looking for methods (iptables rules, etc...) to prevent the version from showing on a nmap report for VSFTPD.

Currently, when executing: nmap -Pn -p 21 -sV localhost

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000086s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp open  ftp     vsftpd 3.0.3
Service Info: OS: Unix
```

I want version to be hidden or display some not valid value(unavailable for example).

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000086s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp open  ftp
Service Info: OS: Unix
```

OS info:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:        7.11
Codename:       wheezy
VSFTPD version: 2.3.5

I have already tried with ftpd_banner and banner_file none of them works.
How can i do this?

Comment: Did you restart the service after changing `ftpd_banner`?

Answer (score 2):

Edit vsftp config file:

```
vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

and uncomment ftpd_banner setting:

```
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the strings at `prelogin.c`
https://github.com/dagwieers/vsftpd/blob/master/prelogin.c